# Android Studio Instrumentation testing build variant

Tags: android-studio, android-testing, android-espresso, android-instrumentation

So I am trying to write instrumentation tests using a custom build variant, mock. In this build variant I mocked up my classes and server. When I try using the mock build myself it works fine, but I can't seem to use my mock build for testing. Here's what my configuration looks like inside Android Studio.

[image: Build Variants]

I had some issues getting my tests to run so I tried to uninstall all versions of my app except my mock version and I keep getting this error:

> Test running startedTest running failed: Unable to find instrumentation target package: com.teamtreehouse.review.debug

However when I try to run my tests against the debug build variant it works fine. It installs my debug version then proceeds to run the tests.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You **can** do testing on a different build variant; but only on one. The default is debug.

See this:
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-tips#change-the-test-build-type

> Currently only one Build Type is tested. By default it is the debug
>   Build Type, but this can be reconfigured with:

```
android {
    ...
    testBuildType "staging"
}
```

Comment: @sunlir  You are a god save !

Comment: You can dynamically test different build type. See my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/51719271/8034839

Answer (score 11):

Alternatively, you can configure your **testBuildType** as following way so that you can decide to run any build type of the androidTest specifying the respective property from command line.

```
android {   
    ...

    if (project.hasProperty('androidTestRelease')) {
        testBuildType 'release'
    } else if (project.hasProperty('androidTestStaging')) {
        testBuildType 'staging'
    } else {
        testBuildType 'debug'
    }
    ...
}
```

From command line

```
./gradlew connectedCheck -PandroidTestStaging
```

Comment: I was wondering why you need to write this code instead of declaring the `testBuildType` for each flavor block. Looks like it's not supported at the moment, as Gradle always consider the last `testBuildType` (doesn't matter where it is placed).

Answer (score 7):

AFAIK androidTest only works against the debug buildType.

You can use build flavours to do what you want, a good example can be found here: https://www.code-labs.io/codelabs/android-testing/#0