# Android Studio Integration test cannot resolve symbol AndroidJUnit4

Tags: android, android-studio, compiler-errors, integration-testing, undefined-symbol

I've seen partial answers to similiar issues but never one that actually solved the problem. I've boiled this down to a minimal app to demonstrate the issue.

I'm using the most current version of Android Studio (V2.2.1)
I have the following SDK's installed:

- Android SDK Tools                v25.1.6
- Android SDK Platform-tools       v23.1
- Android SDK Build-tools          v23.0.3
- Android Support repository      v32

  1. Create new Android app using wizard
  2. Updated build.gradle (app) per: https://developer.android.com/training/testing/start/index.html#config-instrumented-tests

     - Added under defaultConfig:

       - testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
     - Added under dependencies

       - androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.0.1'  <-- Changed to 23.4.0 to match newly generated app
       - androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.4.1'
       - androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.4.1'
  3. Did project sync to sync Gradle
  4. Under the "test" package add new test file - ExampleIntegrationTest.java (right next to ExampleUnitTest.java)
  5. In the new file, created integration test per:  https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/instrumented-unit-tests.html

---

```
import android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4;
import android.test.suitebuilder.annotation.SmallTest;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;


@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@SmallTest
public interface ExampleIntegrationTest {
}
```

---

This is where the problem comes up - cannot resolve symbol AndroidJUnit4
        On the line: import android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4;

If I type the import statement I can use the popup suggestions:
    - import android. - It shows "support as option"
    - import android.support. - It shows "test" as an option
    - import android.support.test. -  Now it only shows "rule" as a option

After I create the app I make sure it's using the "debug" variant

This is pretty cut and dry. As far as I can tell this should work,, but the support library for some reason isn't getting imported correctly.

Comment: did you ever get this? I've seen it before, it disappeared, I have a feeling that it's related to the dependencies being updated underneath my own. So sick of seeing 'try doing it the right way and use the androidTest folder'

Answer (score 8):

Fix this by adding the test to the

- /app/src/androidTest   Directory instead of the
- /app/src/test          Directory which is for unit tests only

Or, when you create the test class, add the test by selecting new class when in "Android Instrumentation Tests" tab of the Project tree

Comment: /app/src/androidTest/java to be precise because I missed that java directory and it was behaving totally different.

Comment: reading this made me feel so stupid(not exaggerating enough). Thanks a lot for this. You, sir, get an upvote for helping the stupid ones.

Comment: If anyone is still seeing this issue and you are using a non-standard build variant, this answer may help you:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/34778780/4672234

Answer (score 2):

Please ensure you have your tests located at the right folder.  There are local and instrumentation tests which must be resided in their respective folders as explained below:

**[Take a look at this article](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/instrumented-unit-tests.html)** which says...

> Run Instrumented Unit Tests To run your instrumented tests, follow
>   these steps:
>
> Be sure your project is synchronized with Gradle by clicking Sync
>   Project  in the toolbar. Run your test in one of the following ways:
>   To run a single test, open the Project window, and then right-click a
>   test and click Run . To test all methods in a class, right-click a
>   class or method in the test file and click Run . To run all tests in a
>   directory, right-click on the directory and select Run tests . The
>   Android Plugin for Gradle compiles the instrumented test code located
>   in the default directory (src/androidTest/java/), builds a test APK
>   and production APK, installs both APKs on the connected device or
>   emulator, and runs the tests. Android Studio then displays the results
>   of the instrumented test execution in the Run window.

Therefore folks,  for **instrumentation test the folder must be (do not forget the case)**

> src/androidTest/java

and for **local tests the folder must be**

> src/test/java

You can then have your package folder(s) to match your app package

Hope, this helps for the community!