# Unresolved references when running espresso tests with release build type

Tags: android, android-espresso

I am trying to run an espresso test with release build type for qa purposes, with the configuration suggested on this answer [Android Studio Instrumentation testing build variant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32484985/android-studio-instrumentation-testing-build-variant). The test runs successfuly with the debug build type, but with the release type I get the following error

```
Warning:there were 118 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
Warning:there were 8 instances of library classes depending on program classes.
Warning:there were 3 unresolved references to program class members.
Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.

Error:Execution failed for task ':Offrie:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForQaReleaseAndroidTest'.
> Job failed, see logs for details
```

Following is the espresso test

```
@MediumTest
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class MainActivityInstrumentationTest {

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> activityRule
            = new ActivityTestRule<>(
            MainActivity.class,
            true,
            false);

    @Test
    public void shouldShowNotificationContentWhenActivityIsDestroyed() {
        final String NOTIFICATION_TITLE = "Título";
        final String NOTIFICATION_CONTENT = "Texto";

        Intent intent = buildNotificationIntent(NOTIFICATION_TITLE, NOTIFICATION_CONTENT);

        activityRule.launchActivity(intent);

        onView(withId(R.id.notification_title)).check(matches(allOf(withText(NOTIFICATION_TITLE), isDisplayed())));
        onView(withId(R.id.notification_content)).check(matches(allOf(withText(NOTIFICATION_CONTENT), isDisplayed())));
    }

    @NonNull
    private Intent buildNotificationIntent(String NOTIFICATION_TITLE, String NOTIFICATION_CONTENT) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();

        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intent.putExtra(NotificationsUtils.NOTIFICATION_TITLE_PARAMETER, NOTIFICATION_TITLE);
        intent.putExtra(NotificationsUtils.NOTIFICATION_TEXT_PARAMETER, NOTIFICATION_CONTENT);
        return intent;
    }
```

And these are two screenshots of the output

[image]

[image]

How can I solve this dependency issue?

Comment: This looks like a proguard issue and does not have anything to do with Espresso. Also, you should copy and paste the error messages, not post screenshots.