# androidTest not compiling, showing cannot resolve symbol

Tags: android, android-studio, junit, android-gradle-plugin, android-testing

I'm trying to add instrumented test using Espresso in my android project.

I've added all necessary libs, besides adding **AndroidJUnitRunner** as the *testInstrumentationRunner*:

> [image: app -> build.gradle]

But for some reason, the imports are not working in **instrumented test** file:

> [image: androidTest file]

But the **local test** file is getting the imports properly:

> [image: local test file]

I've also added **junit** as *androidTestImplementation*, but makes no difference:

```
androidTestImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

This is why I cannot run the test file.

If I run the file anyway, I get this error:

```
Process finished with exit code 1
Class not found: "com.mcp.shippax.MainActivityEspressoTest"Empty test suite.
```

I cannot understand why this is happening (numerous grade syncs/invalidate caches/restarts), when the setup is so straight and simple.

I don't remember making any project changes other than converting most of my source files to Kotlin, including the test files. But later I reverted the test files back to java again.

Comment: Are you putting your test file in `test` or `androidTest` folder?

Comment: @BachVu in androidTest obviously :-) https://pasteboard.co/I0VLPBz.png.

Comment: Then it won't work, what you are doing is unit test, create test file in `test` folder

Comment: Um.. why do u think it's unit test? and what should I do to make it instrumented test? Fyi.. I'm simply trying this: https://github.com/google-developer-training/android-fundamentals-apps-v2/blob/master/TwoActivitiesEspresso/app/src/androidTest/java/com/example/android/twoactivities/ActivityInputOutputTest.java

Comment: Oh my bad, I'm messing it up. Now, from what I'm seeing, you might be missing this `androidTestImplementation org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit:..`

Comment: Nope, didn't work. And why should kotlin lib be added. The file is in java, not kotlin. As I mentioned, I converted the test file to kotlin at first, but then reverted back to java again.

Comment: I thought you said the error is when you converted to Kotlin

Comment: I converted at first, but then reverted back to java, that's what I meant in the last lines.

Comment: Ok, and you said you had it but I want to confirm that you added this line `testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"` right?

Comment: Yep.. not androidx, but android-> testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. I've had various build types for dev and prod environments and what helped me, was to specify testBuildType like in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/34778780/9736105.

So something like this:

```
android {

    ...

    testBuildType "<my-build-type>"

    buildTypes {
        <my-build-type> {
            ...  
        }
        ....
    }
}
```

After I did that and set my build variant to that build type, I was able to resolve all dependecies.

Comment: Do anyone knows why ? Is there something specific to call ?